# Concatenate and remove td cells in beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I have a table like this (old html):

```html
<table>
<!-- Begin Table Body -->
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">U.S. federal statutory income tax rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">35.0</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">35.0</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Federal income tax at statutory rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap="">$</td>
<td align="right">(2,813</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">$</td>
<td align="right">5,834</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">State and local income taxes, net of federal income tax effect</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">(733</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">812</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 1px">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px"> </div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="1"/> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="1"/> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Provision (benefit) for income taxes</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap="">$</td>
<td align="right">(3,546</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">$</td>
<td align="right">6,646</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 1px">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px"> </div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="4"/> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="4"/> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Effective income tax rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">44.1</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">39.9</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
</tr>
<!-- End Table Body -->
</table>
```

and I want it to look like:

U.S. federal statutory income tax rate 35.0% 35.0%

Federal income tax at statutory rate $(2,813) $5,834

State and local income taxes, net of federal income tax effect (733) 812

Provision (benefit) for income taxes $(3,546) $6,646

Effective income tax rate 44.1% 39.9%

I have two problems getting from the code to the code above to the table below:
1. there are empty cells like  
2. some values are distributed over cells

I want to get rid of the empty cells by decomposing them and concatenate some cells like (2,813 and ) or 44.1 and %

I tried the following code for decomposing but it does not work and I have no clue how to concatenate cells in BeautifulSoup:

```py
s= """<table>
<!-- Begin Table Body -->
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">U.S. federal statutory income tax rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">35.0</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">35.0</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Federal income tax at statutory rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap="">$</td>
<td align="right">(2,813</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">$</td>
<td align="right">5,834</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">State and local income taxes, net of federal income tax effect</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">(733</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">812</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 1px">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px"> </div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="1"/> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="1"/> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Provision (benefit) for income taxes</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap="">$</td>
<td align="right">(3,546</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">$</td>
<td align="right">6,646</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 1px">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px"> </div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="4"/> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="4"/> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Effective income tax rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">44.1</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">39.9</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
</tr>
<!-- End Table Body -->
</table>"""
soup = bs(s, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table')
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        if cell.text=='':
            cell.decompose()

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you can isolate the right table then just loop the trs within attribute `valign` and concantenate the tds where != ' '

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<table>
<!-- Begin Table Body -->
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">U.S. federal statutory income tax rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">35.0</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">35.0</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Federal income tax at statutory rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap="">$</td>
<td align="right">(2,813</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">$</td>
<td align="right">5,834</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">State and local income taxes, net of federal income tax effect</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">(733</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">812</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 1px">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px"> </div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="1"/> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="1"/> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Provision (benefit) for income taxes</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap="">$</td>
<td align="right">(3,546</td>
<td nowrap="">)</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">$</td>
<td align="right">6,646</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="font-size: 1px">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px"> </div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="4"/> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"><hr noshade="" size="4"/> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background: #eeeeee" valign="bottom">
<td><div style="margin-left:10px; text-indent:-10px">Effective income tax rate</div></td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">44.1</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap=""> </td>
<td align="right">39.9</td>
<td nowrap="">%</td>
</tr>
<!-- End Table Body -->
</table>'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.select('table tr[valign]'):
    print(' '.join([td.text for td in tr.select('td') if td.text != ' ']))
```

---

[image]